# Adding data to many-to-many field of a modelform within a view

Tags: django, django-forms

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Entry(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=True, null=True)

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
```

In my view, I need to add pk id's to a submitted form before saving it.

```
data = request.POST.copy()
# 'person' is a ManyToManyField to a 'Person' model
# a form would normally send multiple id's as POST in this format -> u'id': [u'1', u'2']
# u'1,2' (an example) is a str variable accessible to the view
data[u'person'] = u'1,2'.split(",") 
form = MyModelForm(data)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

This gives me:

> int() argument must be a string or a
>   number, not 'list'

Which is fair enough. It does work in case of:

```
data[u'person'] = u'1'
```

I also tried this with no success:

```
new_form = form.save(commit=False)
new_form.person = u'1,2'.split(",")
new_form.save()
form.save_m2m()
```

**How can I save multiple id's to this ManyToManyField?**
Must be easy but I am missing the point.

---

EDIT:
The desired result is one new instance of MyModelForm (in the 'entry' table) with all id's stored for form.person (multiple records in the 'entry_person' table).

---

**UPDATE:**
I seem to have isolated the problem.

If I do:

```
data = {}  
data[u'person'] = u'1,2'.split(",")
```

It **does work** as the result is:

```
{u'person': [u'1', u'2'],}
```

If I do:

```
data = request.POST.copy()  
data[u'person'] = u'1,2'.split(",")
```

It **does NOT work** (gives the error described above) as the result is:

```
<QueryDict: {u'person': [[u'1', u'2']],}>
```

So all I need is to have

```
<QueryDict: {u'person': [u'1', u'2'],}>
```

Any suggestions how?

Comment: Can you post the code for the model and form?

Comment: Thanks! This is weird but I think I've found what causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QueryDict.setlist(key, list_)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.setlist) solves this problem.

Answered in [A workaround for Django QueryDict wrapping values in lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618699/a-workaround-for-django-querydict-wrapping-values-in-lists)

Answer (score 0):

The split you entered returns the following:

```
[u'1', u'2']
```

To create multiple instances in your database you'd need to iterate over the list:

```
for x in u'1,2'.split(","):
  data[u'person'] = x
  form = MyModelForm(data)
  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Out of curiosity, why string to list conversion in the first place? Or is this just a general example

Comment: Thank you! This creates n records of MyModelForm (each having 'person' = x from the for loop), where n = number of items in the [].  What I need is to create one record of MyModelForm and store n id's for 'person'.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new_form.person = [int(x) for x in u'1,2'.split(",")]
```

This will set new_form.person to a list of ints, not a list of strings.

Comment: Thank you! This does not work.  
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'