# A workaround for Django QueryDict wrapping values in lists?

Tags: django

Hopefully this is an easy one.
Problem: **Django QueryDict wraps values in lists.**

This:

```
data[u'test'] = [u'1', u'2']
```

Becomes:

```
<QueryDict: {u'test': [[u'1', u'2']]}>
```

How do I make it:

```
<QueryDict: {u'test': [u'1', u'2']}>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
data.setlist( 'test', [u'1', u'2'] )
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/?from=olddocs#django.http.QueryDict.setlist

Comment: Sorry: not brilliant.  Just more patient at searching the documentation.

Comment: Can't deny it's a RTFM question and I missed this method in the docs :)

Comment: @dmi: Don't blame me as brilliant -- patient, perhaps.

Comment: I have `[{'id': 'UUID-96', 'name': 'with_edge', 'coordinates': [[[2240.348,1627.8890000000001],[2169.08378125,1611.014453125]]]}, {...}]` and wondering how can I change this coordinates from list of list to list.