# int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm rendering out 3 multiple select boxes on my form. 
I'm filtering each box out to have a seperate type of day.
When I submit my form I get this error.

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'
```

**What must I do to save my form?**

This is what i'm doing on my forms.py file to get the different filtering for each select box.

```
class ContractForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, project_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContractForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['shoot_day'].queryset = Day.objects.filter(type=SHOOT, project__id=project_id)
        self.fields['travel_day'].queryset = Day.objects.filter(type=TRAVEL, project__id=project_id)
        self.fields['additional_day'].queryset = Day.objects.filter(type=ADDITIONAL, project__id=project_id)
```

---

I'm getting my project_id like so:

```
def editcontract(request, contract_id, slug):
    context_dict = {}
    contract = get_object_or_404(Contract, pk=contract_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContractForm(request.POST, instance=contract)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            TvUsageForm = TvUsageFormSet(request.POST, instance=contract)
            AdditionalMediaUsageForm = AdditionalMediaUsageFormSet(request.POST, instance=contract)
            TvUsageForm.save()
            AdditionalMediaUsageForm.save()
            return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contract_list', kwargs={'slug':slug}))
    else:
        form = ContractForm(instance=contract, project_id=contract.project_id)
        TvUsageForm = TvUsageFormSet(instance=contract)
        AdditionalMediaUsageForm = AdditionalMediaUsageFormSet(instance=contract)
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=slug)
        context_dict = { 'form': form,
                         'tvusage_form':TvUsageForm,
                         'additional_form':AdditionalMediaUsageForm,
                         'project':project
        }
    return render_to_response('contracts/edit_contract.html', context_dict, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Since you don't show where you get `project_id` from, we are unable to help you.

Comment: updated. please see my edit on the question. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a confusion with the argument list and keyword arguments:

Instead of:

```
ContractForm(instance=contract, project_id=contract.project_id)
```

You want:

```
ContractForm(contract.project_id, instance=contract)
```

To elaborate: Your constructor accepts the project id as first argument not as keyword argument. Thus you need to give it as first argument. Simple confusion, eh?

Comment: I don't have a problem with the initial rendering of the form. But I did try what you suggested. I still get that same error when I submit my form. Based on your suggestion I tried `form = ContractForm(request.POST, contract.project_id, instance=contract)` but still I get the same problem.

Comment: You were right! I changed `form = ContractForm(contract.project_id, request.POST, instance=contract)` and it worked. I understand now what you mean about the order of arguments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you: [Adding data to many-to-many field of a modelform within a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595009/adding-data-to-many-to-many-field-of-a-modelform-within-a-view)

Comment: I there. That looks very similar to my problem. However I don't know where to do a setlist in my case?